# Adding <!DOCTYPE html> to my code prevents CSS external rules from applying

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage that I am trying to validate with w3. It says I need to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the page above the `<html>` tag so I did. As a result, my CSS messed up.

Using the "web developer" in the latest Firefox, I saw that the CSS file is loading over the network just fine, but under the style editor, it says for that CSS file `0 rules` even though there should be `25 rules`. When I edit the CSS file in the style editor (even simply hitting the enter button on a new line) it applies the CSS file and everything works just fine.

I also tried taking the CSS code and putting it directly into the html file and it works then to.

So the problem is when I load the CSS externally. I have done lots of research and the most common suggestions say:

1. Adding the  switches modes to quirks mode (or visa versa) and to include `html,body{height:100%;}` in your CSS. (Check and already done, no differences)
2. Make sure to use the `type="text/css"` (Check and already done, no differences)
3. End the link tag with a `/>` (Check and already done, no differences)

Does anyone have any idea why the web browser is not applying my css code?

Here are some code samples:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>StudiOm Yoga, Jackson MS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="libraries/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        <?php
            if($_SESSION['generalsettings']['showwelcomemessage'] == "checked")
            {
        ?>
        $( function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
        } );
        <?php
            }
            else
            {
        ?>
        $( function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).hide();
        } );
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </script>



    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/default.php"/>


    </head>
```

My head section including the beginning html tag and doctype html tag.

```
body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
            color: #ffffff;
            }


            a:-webkit-any-link {
                color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
                cursor: grabbing;
            }
            a:link {
            color:inherit;
            }

            .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3, .bgimg-4, .bgimg-5 {
            position: relative;
            opacity: 0.65;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;

            }
            .bgimg-1 {
            background-image: url("../images/website/allsmaller2.jpeg");
            min-height: 100%;


            background-repeat: repeat;
            background-position: left;
            background-size: 100% auto;

            }


            .bgimg-2 {
            background-image: url("../images/website/ddog.jpg");
            min-height: 60%;
            }

            .bgimg-3 {
            background-image: url("../images/website/leg.jpg");
            min-height: 60%;
            }

            .bgimg-4 {
            background-image: url("../images/website/hangingwide.jpeg");
            min-height: 60%;
            }

            .bgimg-5 {
            background-image: url("../images/website/yoga5.jpg");
            min-height: 100%;
            }

            .caption {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 50%;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            color: #000;
            }

            .title
            {
                display:inline;
                background-color: #111;
                color: #fff;
                border-radius: 6px;
                padding: 15px;
                margin: 0% 0%;
                font-size: 25px;
                letter-spacing: 10px;
            }

            .caption span.border {
            background-color: #111;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 18px;
            font-size: 25px;
            letter-spacing: 10px;
            }

            h3 {
                letter-spacing: 5px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font: 20px "Lato", sans-serif;
                color: #777;
            }




            .larger
            {
                font-size: 50;
            }
            a:visited
            {
                color:#ffffff;
            }

            div.table {font-size:20px;display: table;border:1px solid white; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:85%;}
            div.tablerow {display:table-row; border:1px solid white; text-align:center;}
            div.tablecol {display:table-cell; border:1px solid white;}
            div.schedule {padding: 10px;}

            div.table2 {font-size:20px;display: table; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:85%;}
            div.tablerow2 {display:table-row;  text-align:center;}
            div.tablecol2 {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}


            div.tile 
            {
                display: inline-block;
                max-height: 300px;
                max-width: 200px;

                box-shadow: 5px 5px grey;
                border: 2px solid black;
                margin: 20px 20px;
            }




            #sn
            {
                filter:invert(100%);
            }

            /* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones */
            @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
                .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
                    background-attachment: scroll;
                }
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) 
            {               
                div.table {display:block; border:1px solid white;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:75%;}
                div.tablerow {display:block;border:1px solid white;}
                div.tablecol {display:block;border:1px solid white;padding:10px;}

                div.table2 {display:block; border:1px solid white;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:75%;}
                div.tablerow2 {display:block;border:1px solid white;}
                div.tablecol2 {display:block;border:1px solid white;padding:10px;}
            }
```

My CSS file that is not being applied.

Comment: Suggestions #2 and #3 are outdated. HTML5 no longer requires type="text/css", and [/> comes from XHTML/XML; HTML has never required it, and still doesn't](https://blog.novalistic.com/archives/2017/08/optional-end-tags-in-html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JS you have in your body is whacked, the syntax is all wrong. Also that PHP won't process if it's in a straight html file as it will not run through the php parser. I'd reckon that's your issue right there. PHP is a preprocessor that generates html, you cant just put it in an html file and have it run. Since it's in a script tag and in the head, it won't output in the body, but if you use inspector in whatever browser you're using, you'll see it in the script tag in the markup.

The reason the PHP is parsing without the doctype declaration, is I am assuming because whatever server you're running this code on is assuming it's a php file instead of html.  If you want to deliver dynamic css via a php file, you could call the php file externally like you would a css file eg: mysite.com/style.php.

Don't forget that if you're delivering dynamic css to users, to practice proper sanitization prior, eg using CSS tidy or some other method of validation and escaping. Ideally if you can do so, do the escaping/sanitizing on save, rather than on delivery, to lower overhead on your server for every call as well as to speed up the delivery to the end user. However, that's somewhat irrelevant if you're caching the css anyways.

Style.php would look something like this.

```
echo header("Content-type: text/css");
header("Pragma: nocache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Last-Modified: " . date("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
echo $css_stuffz_goes_here;
exit // or die
```

Comment: The second to last line of code is <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/default.php"/> on the first block of code. (See my #2) Isn't that correct?

Comment: The PHP and javascript work just fine when the <!DOCTYPE html> isn't there. Also when I simply activate the CSS file in the firefox style editor, everything works just fine.

Comment: Okay changing my `default.php` file to `default.css` (both the name of the actual file and the text) fixed it...

However, how can I make it so my CSS files are dynamic? I might have a user who wants to be able to modify the css files through a portal, so I want the CSS files to be automatically generated like the html files are