# Include myself as CSS file in php while declaring doctype

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a somewhat unique project. In this project I need to contain everything in one file.

My file will output the html code to draw the page, and the CSS is a reference to itself with a parameter.
My thought was, since its php, if the parameter is set, output only CSS and we're good to go. But somehow the CSS never gets this. After a lot of digging, it seems that the moment I declare a `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the html part (not css), the CSS is not working. If I remove that line, all works correctly.

Here's my code inside `display.php`:

```php
<?php

if( $_GET['css'] == 'main' )
{
    echo
    'BODY {
        font-size: 8pt;
        background-color:#EEA;
    }
    span:after{content: " - DEBUG:'.$_GET['css'].'";}
    ';

}
else
{

echo 
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Mon, 22 Jul 2002 11:12:01 GMT">
        <title>My Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="display.php?css=main" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
';
        echo '<br><span>test</span>';

}
```

I'd like to declare a `<!DOCTYPE ...`> obviously. I was using strict xhtml 1.0 earlier, but troubleshooting lead me to the most basic form of html 5.0 not working either.

What can I do to get it working?

Comment: "*I need to contain everything in one file.*" Certainly tangential to the question at hand, but may I ask *why*? This seems like a pretty poor design choice and makes source control and maintenance activities much, **much** harder than they have to be.

Comment: @esqew I know what you mean, for this project I just have to. I'm creating a system that I can quickly deploy and not need to worry about having to upload many files, and when I replace it, I just get that one file out, not looking for different files that may have been placed. I also don't want to use inline stylesheet etc because I don't want it to be visible to the outside that just one file is responsible, and I don't want to setup weird folder structures. Just a matter of creating a new index.php, paste code in and go.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Barmar None. Console shows nothing. Then again, if I go into inspect mode, it shows no CSS either. The file is treated as empty file.

Comment: Does the Sources tab list `display.php?css=main`? Do you see it trying to load the script in the Network tab?

Comment: @Barmar yes, and as soon as I remove the `<!DOCTYPE=html>` row from the html section, everything works correctly.

Comment: Also, if I print the CSS outright in the file, it starts to work, which makes it even weirder.

Comment: What if you remove `media="screen"`?

Comment: @Barmar removing media=screen does not change anything. If I however print {} at the start of the page, so the doctype declaration is not on the first line, it all works again, but that {} is also visible on the main page.

Comment: AFAIK, `<!DOCTYPE...>` always has to be the first thing in the HTML page or it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I am okay if I have to include this file in another script, and go about it the other way. Detect a way to know if I was included, if not, then only show CSS. I'm sure that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

I googled for doctype prevents CSS and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48605112/adding-doctype-html-to-my-code-prevents-css-external-rules-from-applying/48605133) article that explained what was happening.

Because I declare html in the source, once the css is loaded, it expects it to be html (which is not CSS), and such the php code is not executed. If I remove the DOCTYPE row, the browser sees .php and treats it as a PHP file allowing CSS.

The answer suggested to prepend the following code in my CSS section:

```php
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    header("Pragma: nocache");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: " . date("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
```

and that fixed it. :) yay